# What is our stance on questions about tool requests?

Tags: discussion, scope

What is our stance on questions about tool requests? Are they on-topic or off-topic?

Example 1: [Are there any online tools available for entering Korean text?](https://korean.stackexchange.com/q/171/3)

> This issue came up somtime during the commitment phase. How do I go about entering Hanguel?

Example 2:  [Is there any program for Microsoft Windows for dictating Korean text?](https://korean.stackexchange.com/q/189/3)

> Neither Dragon NaturallySpeaking nor Microsoft Speech Recognition
>   allows dictation to Korean text. Is there any program for Microsoft
>   Windows for dictating Korean text?
>
> I am aware that there exist some online solution, such as Google
>   dictation in Google Documents, but as far as I know it only allows to
>   dictate within the browser.

Answer (score 5):

I'd like to see requests of this type **on-topic**, when they are specifically about tools and resources relevant to the Korean language. This isn't ever likely to be the highest-traffic SE site and I think we should do our best to make it a broadly-useful resource.

Comment: I agree with this; these are actual, useful questions within the context of learning the language even though they're not directly related to it.

Comment: @dotVezz I'm a bit confused: since you agree with this answer that says the two questions are on-topic, why did you vote to close the second question? (or maybe you voted to reopen afterward?)

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Yesterday there hadn't been any real discussion about it. I voted off-topic because it seemed like it *was* off-topic, although I even mentioned in my comments on that question that - in my opinion - I hoped we could find a way to use questions like it. That said, now that we've had discussion and everyone seems to agree, I have voted to re-open and am pretty happy with the result.

Answer (score 5):

It's possible that we will get users who are not very computer savvy and possibly not even very stackexchange savvy, so allowing people to ask about computer tools that can assist in learning Korean **should be on-topic**.